# {webpack} К двум html файлам подключается один файл css, что делать?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, sass

Надо, чтобы к каждому `html` файлу подключался только определенный файл `css` (`sass`).

webpack:

```js
plugins: [
  new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: './src/index.html',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: isProd
    }
  }),
  new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'laptops.html',
    template: './src/laptops.html',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: isProd
    }
  }),
  new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].css'
  })
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS подключается к сборке через js чанка.

Чтобы сделать два разных .css для двух html тебе нужно создать два разных чанка (entry), подключить в них разные .css и в HtmlWebpackPlugin в опции chunks указать наименование чанка с .css, который тебе нужен.